# Distance Between Any Two Points on a Unit Circle

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

As part of a larger investigation, I am required to be able to calculate the distance between any two points on a unit circle. I have tried to use cosine law but I can't determine any specific manner in which I can calculate theta if the angle between the two points and the positive axis is always given.

Is there any manner in which I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_(geometry)#Chords_in_trigonometry

Comment: I already read that but I don't think it really helped.

Comment: Did you learn dot product?

Comment: Yes I did...I'll try to look into that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the arc distance between the two points is $\theta$, the length of the chord between them is $2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$:

[image: geometry diagram]

Comment: @ProgramFun: Sounds like you should just subtract the two values you know. (You may end up with a negative value of $2\sin\frac\theta2$, but just take the absolute value of that). Unless the "angles between each point and the positive $x$-axis" are not always measured in the same direction, that is. (And if they aren't, then you need more data).

Comment: Thanks for that, I had just figured that out myself right before your post and was spending time testing it. Is there any name for the formula you suggested?

Comment: @ProgramFun: I don't think it has a fancy distinguished name, but you won't go much wrong by calling it, say "the chord-length formula". Or even the "chord formula", if it's alright by you that attempts to google it will return lots of noise about musical notation.

Comment: That diagram rates a +1! :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

- Points on the unit circle centered at $(0,0)$ on the argand plane are of the form $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$, with $0 \leq \theta \lt 2\pi$.
- Can you use **distance formula** now to calculate the requires to distance?

---

With some knowledge in complex numbers, you'd realise that,  if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are two complex numbers, the amplitude, $|z_1-z_2|$ is the distance between the two of them.